# Python merge based on column position

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have 2 dataframes like so,

```
ID employee        group
1      Bob   Accounting
2     Jake  Engineering
3     Lisa  Engineering
4      Sue           HR

ID employee  hire_date
1     Lisa       2004
2      Bob       2008
3     Jake       2012
4      Sue       2014
```

Now I'd like to merge these two dataframes on the `employee` column. Only the thing is, rather than mentioning the column name `employee`, I need to mention only the position of the employee column which I will know.

Simply put, I would like to merge the 2 dataframes on `employee` **column without mentioning the column name, rather by mentioning column position only.**

Now I tried something like this,

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4], 'employee': ['Bob', 'Jake', 'Lisa', 'Sue'],
                    'group': ['Accounting', 'Engineering', 'Engineering', 'HR']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4],'employee': ['Lisa', 'Bob', 'Jake', 'Sue'],
                    'hire_date': [2004, 2008, 2012, 2014]})

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on=df1.ix[:,[1]], right_on=df2.ix[:,[1]])
```

But it is throwing ValueError. So could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1.merge(df2, right_on=df2.columns[1], left_on=df1.columns[1])
```

Output:

```
   ID_x employee        group  ID_y  hire_date
0     1      Bob   Accounting     2       2008
1     2     Jake  Engineering     3       2012
2     3     Lisa  Engineering     1       2004
3     4      Sue           HR     4       2014
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list(df)` to access a list of column names which you can reference by position:

```
merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = list(df1)[1], right_on = list(df2)[1])
```

Output:

```
   ID_x employee        group  ID_y  hire_date
0     1      Bob   Accounting     2       2008
1     2     Jake  Engineering     3       2012
2     3     Lisa  Engineering     1       2004
3     4      Sue           HR     4       2014
```